# Uninstall MySQL from macOS

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

Trying to unistall MySQL completely but can see 'grep mysql' process after reboot. Can not kill that process its changing PID. Any suggestions?

Comment: How it was installed? Using downloaded .pkg file or using brew!!!

Comment: 1. Install latest version MySQL with brew 2. Unistall it with brew 3. Download 5.7 MySQL as .dmg file and installed it

Comment: Then answer given by @Damian Dziaduch will work!
Check more info `brew info mysql`

Comment: Well, but 'grep mysql' process is still there..

Answer (score 2):

To stop the services you can use one of these:

- `brew services stop mysql`
- `mysql.server stop`

Then you can uninstall it with `brew uninstall mysql`. But database files will remain, so to clear them just do `rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql`

Cheers.

Comment: Already removed /usr/local/var/mysql, brew said theres no service "mysql" started, and can't run mysql.server, because it was deleted

Comment: @zzheads what about reboot?

Comment: Did it for sure )

Comment: @zzheads that is creepy. What if you create a new user on mac? Will it have mysql process also? Maybe try to find what is starting the process. I am pretty sure that this has an answer on StackOverFlow already ;)

Comment: Made different user, logged him: 8718 ttys003    0:00.00 grep mysql

Comment: Same process as under admin